# Using $rootScope and $broadcast to communicate between functions

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my app I have one page that shows the details of a particular users document in which a document can be deleted and another that shows the users recently viewed documents. I'm trying to make it so when a user deletes a document in the view page it also deletes the listing in the users recently viewed documents history.

I'm attempting to use $broadcast and $rootScope to communicate between the two modules but I suspect I'm doing something wrong with the syntax or there's an issue with scope or project structure.

Here's the two separate functions that delete the different entries

**history.js**

```
//gets the selected item the user clicks and deletes it and updates history
$scope.removeFavorite = function(item) {
  var items = $scope.recent[item.type];

  item = items.splice(items.indexOf(item), 1)[0];

  $rootScope.$on('deleteRecent', function(data) {
    historyManager.remove(data);
  });

  historyManager.remove(item).then(loadHistoryItems, loadHistoryItems);
};
```

**documentView.js**

```
//confirmation that user wants selected document deleted
function confirmDelete() {
  var delObj = _.pick(sDocument, 'Doc_Type', 'Doc_Num');

  repos
    .sDoc
    .del(delObj);

  var item = sDocument.Doc_Type + ';' + sDocument.Doc_Num;

  $rootScope.$broadcast('deleteRecent', item);

  tabBarViewModel.removeTabByState($state.get('sDocument'), delObj);

  $scope.modalOptions.hide();
}
```

Comment: When you say modules, do you mean controllers ? And if it's the case, why are using events instead of services when services are by definition the intended means of communication in AngularJS ?

Comment: using `$broadcast` is just bad practice. I would avoid it if possible at all.

Comment: I am using controllers, I apologize, I'm still pretty new to Angular. So I should create a service that works in place of the $broadcast function I'm calling?

Answer (score 0):

Given that your rootScope injection is fine your problematic part is this one:

```
$scope.removeFavorite = function(item) {
  var items = $scope.recent[item.type];

  item = items.splice(items.indexOf(item), 1)[0];

  $rootScope.$on('deleteRecent', function(data) {
    historyManager.remove(data);
  });

  historyManager.remove(item).then(loadHistoryItems, loadHistoryItems);
};
```

First if you're using $rootScope to broadcast, message can be received on any $scope, other then that, you don't wrap it into function on $scope and first parameter is event.

So correct code would look like this:

```
$scope.$on('deleteRecent', function(event, data) {
    historyManager.remove(data);
});

$scope.removeFavorite = function(item) {
  var items = $scope.recent[item.type];

  item = items.splice(items.indexOf(item), 1)[0];



  historyManager.remove(item).then(loadHistoryItems, loadHistoryItems);
};
```